# How to override a method in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a module that defines functions that will be shared by other modules. Some of those functions need to be overridden. This is what I was thinking, but it doesn't work:

```
// shared_module.js
module.exports = {
    alternativeFun() {
        exports.doSomething()
        sharedFun()
    },
    sharedFun() {
        console.log('shared')
    }
}

// alternative_module1.js
module.exports = {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('alternative 1')
    }
}

// alternative_module2.js
module.exports = {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('alternative 2')
    }
}

// main.js
const shared1 = require('./shared_module')
shared1.doSomething = require('./alternative_module1').doSomething
shared1.alternativeFun()

const shared2 = require('./shared_module')
shared2.doSomething = require('./alternative_module2').doSomething
shared2.alternativeFun()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `module.exports` does not magically change the value of `exports`. You will need to also assign it to the same value (`module.exports = exports = ...`) if you want to use it inside your module's functions.